# NFS Share in Windows - Drives mapped as folders

Tags: windows, ubuntu, permissions, nfs

I am relatively new to Linux (Ubuntu Server 12.0.4.1), but I am learning quickly. I currently have a Windows 2008 R2 file server set up (not ready yet to change that to Linux, but have plans). The drives are configured as such:

D: (2 x 1 TB RAID 0),
D:\Videos (1 x 2TB drive),
D:\Videos\Television (1 x 2TB drive).

in plain English, I have a drive mapped as D:\, another drive mapped to a folder under D:\ (D:\Videos), and another drive mapped under a folder of a folder (D:\Videos\Television).

I've configured an NFS share to share out the root, and verified that I have proper access to all of the files and folders in the root. However when I try to access the D:\Videos folder from the NFS share, I get `Permission denied.` So, I assume that the NFS permissions I'm setting on the root drive isn't being applied to the sub-folders that exist on separate physical drives.

I can't think of a better way to sum this up, but how do I ensure I can have an NFS share that encompasses all of the files and folders on D:\ (including the drives mapped as folders)?

Comment: Hang on, are you trying to share folders from windows to Linux using NFS? Why not SMB?

Comment: NFS tends to have better performance, especially for streaming high bitrates. But I agree with @terdon, that is definitely a very rare case to do from a windows server.. Curious if performance holds to the typical case too as it was built for Unix.